# sort games in their subfolders

Tags: linux, sorting

Recently I started using Batocera, and I am collecting games. I found on my drive tons of amiga games, which in most cases are in multiple files e.g.

```
samurai1.adf
samurai2.adf
Battleships.adf
exile - d1.adz
exile - d2.adz
exile - d3.adz
Prehistorik.ADF
Dynablaster.adf
Superfrog (Disk 1 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
Superfrog (Disk 2 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
Superfrog (Disk 3 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
Superfrog (Disk 4 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
```

I want to put the files into corresponding subfolders. Something like this

```
├──Dynablaster.adf
├──exile
│  ├──exile - d1.adz
│  ├──exile - d2.adz
│  └──exile - d3.adz
├──Prehistorik.ADF
├──samurai
│  ├──samurai1.adf
│  └──samurai2.adf
└──Superfrog
   ├──Superfrog (Disk 1 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
   ├──Superfrog (Disk 2 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
   ├──Superfrog (Disk 3 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
   └──Superfrog (Disk 4 of 4)[cr CSL].adf
```

But obviously I don't want to do this by sorting them manually. The files are different in just one number. Sometimes the game has just one file, and then I would love to leave this game. I tried to google a script, but I could not find one. I tried to came up with my own script on linux, but it didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I tried to come up with my own script"* - Please consider [edit]ing your question to include this information, even if it wasn't successful.

Comment: The thing is I tried, but I gave up after including libraries…